# Which project type / item in VSTS 2008 helps me model a database?

Tags: database-design, visual-studio-2008, reverse-engineering, visio, forward-engineer

As per the thread: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Applications/Microsoft_Visio/Q_24660513.html I should be able to model a database (like I do in Visio 2007) in Visual Studio Team System 2008. I am unable to find how to achieve this. In no project type am I able to find an item that helps me create a Database Model. I want to do so to be able to reverse & forward engineer database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the [VSTS Database Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/teamsystem/default.mspx#database-edition) to do this.  It includes the designers for these.

For details on usage, see [MSDN's pages on the Database Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172124.aspx).

Comment: You mean that the Team Suite that I have, won't offer design support for Database? When I invoke the VSTS, the splash screen displays "Team System - Architecture Edition", "Team System - Database Edition", "Team System - Development Edition" and "Team System - Test Edition". I did not install them separately. They all came bundled.

Comment: It it is showing Database Edition, you should be fine.  See the MSDN link for usage.  (Some of the VSTS SKUs don't include the Database Edition...)

Comment: Reed, sorry but I cannot figure out the desired information from MSDN. Can you please share a direct URL?

Comment: Really depends on what you want to do.  The getting started section is good.  Here's how to model a DB from scratch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833432.aspx

Comment: Thanks Reed. I kinda get it now but I am somewhat disappointed with the "SQL Server 2008" project type because I was looking for just "Database" project type which will take care of any RDBMS I'd like to work with (MySQL in my case).